# calling multiple methods within a method - selenium webdriver cross browser testing

Tags: java, selenium

I have a question with regards to calling multiple method using JUNIT. This is my test

```
package com.example.tests;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class test {
private WebDriver _driver;

@Test
public void FFconfiguration() throws Exception {
System.out.println("Running FF");
_driver = new FirefoxDriver();
_driver.get("URL");
login();
setup();
_driver.quit();
}

public void login1() 
{
}


public void setup() 
{
}
}
```

My question is: Can I call both login() and setup() within the method FFConfiguration? If not what's the alternate solution...............

Comment: Yes you can do this. JUnit doesn't change the fact that you're using Java that permits this kind of programming.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely, you can do it. You can have tests like this:

```
 @Test
 public void testBuyingProcess(){
   ShoppingUI shoppingPage = new ShoppingUI();
   shoppingPage.login();
   Assert.assertEquals(shoppingPage.getTitle(),"Welcome");
   //....
 }
```

And fill in the methods elsewhere even in different class. Few examples of methods used above:

```
public class ShoppingUI{
   private WebDriver driver

   public ShoppingUI(){
     driver = new FirefoxDriver();
     driver.get("http://my-test-site.com/buy-buy-buy.html");
   }

  public String getTitle(){
     return driver.getTitle();
  }
}
```